# Import fields and field types

Tags: entities

I am developing a Management Information System in Drupal, holding thousands of suppliers in different certification schemes.
 Due to the nature of these certification schemes, and because of working with third parties, I need to import comprehensive surveys in CSV from other systems. I normally do that via feeds which works fine.

The issue now is how to deal with the big variety of D7 fields. In the present situation I need to key in all these fields, and map them to the import fields in the feeds. Lots of work with about 10 surveys carrying approx. 100 questions each.

Survey questions (= fields) and related Field types are however available in CSV.
 Would there be a way of importing Fields and Fields types from such CSV into new or existing content types, similar to https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_auto_field ?

Posted this question before under Entityform, only realizing later that the question would be more relevant under core.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) with the [CSV as a data source](https://www.drupal.org/node/1152158).